# No podspec found for `package` when adding iOS project to existing Ionic 5 project

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5, podspec, capacitor-plugin

I built a Capacitor plugin for Ionic and Capacitor and published it to NPM - call it `test1`. I then use it in my Ionic 5 project and successfully add a new Android project via:

```
ionic build 
ionic cap add android 
ionic cap sync
```

Tested it and it works. I then try and add an iOS via:

```
ionic build 
ionic cap add ios
```

I then get the following error:

````
`[!] No podspec found for `Test1` in `../../node_modules/test1```
````

And it fails. I can't figure out why as there is a `Test1Plugin.podspec` file in the root with relevant dependencies and an `ios/Podfile` with relevant dependencies. I also ensure both files are published to npm.

I tried changing the name of the `.podspec` file to `Test1.podspec` but it's the exact same issue.

I'm pretty stumped and hoping someone has some pointers as i've been on this for a while and tried everything.